# Is it possible to set a default value for Azure DevOps service connections in build tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to implement a custom build task in Azure DevOps for my project. We have for each environment an own subscriptions and one environment-independent subscription. The new task should have the environment-independent one as default.

Here is the relevant code from the task.json.

```
"inputs": [
        {
            "name": "ConnectedServiceName",
            "type": "ConnectedService:AzureRM",
            "label": "Azure Subscription",
            "required": true,
            "defaultValue": "4893b32-2345-ab54-b13d-1294cab34",
            "groupName": "CredentialsSelection"
        },
```

The problem is, that the service endpoint id, which I have specified is ignored. The same behavior occurs, if I specify the name of the service connection endpoint.
Does anybody know if there is a way to specify the default value?

Comment: i don't think it is possible to set default-values for serviceconnections. Doesn't make too much sense to set a defaultvalue for a ServiceConnection because a task can be delivered to multiple organizations and the value would be specific to only ONE organization

Comment: The task belongs only to one Azure DevOps Organization (10 project, ~600 build definitions, ~600 release definitions). Normally, the definitions use the service connection endpoint which is related to the environment (dev, test, ...), but now we have an environment-independent service connection endpoint. Because of that, a default value makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, it was possible to set the default value by using the service connection id. The task needed some time to make the changes available. I don't know why, because I deleted the task before I deployed the new version. But now it works.

As D.J. mentioned, a default value only makes sense if the task is internal and only used within an organization.